# Chrome bug? Content not rendering multi-columns properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/zqdLzya2/

Which is a dead simple 3-column layout.

When you hover an item some of them blink or just disappear for a second. Also when content moves up it goes over the title, disappear and renders fine. Some blinking also occurs when you scroll. Content is displayed fine but does not render.

---

**Update 1**

Elements stop blinking when there's no `CSS transition` or `transform`.

---

**Update 2**

Elements stop blinking or doing anything crazy when there's no `transform` so I've removed the **read more** button.

---

**Update 3**

Bug has been reported here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=460222

---

I've tried the same code on Opera, Firefox and Safari and they all seem to render fine.

Is this a Chrome bug?

Here some screenshots:
[image: How it should work]
[image: How chrome renders the content sometimes when you scroll or hover]

Here is my naked HTML code:

```
<div id="news" class="span-image-title clear content-wrapper">

        <!-- this element repeats -->
        <div class="item">

            <div class="desc bgwhite pdd">
                <h4 class="title-font lightblue">[title goes could be one line title or five]</h4>
                <p class="text-color">2th of January, 2015</p>
            </div>

            <div class="image" style="background-image:url('[image go here, changes with each item]');"></div>

            <div class="desc-body">
                <div class="table-wrap">
                    <div class="table-cell">
                        <div class="entry-content pdd">
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, debitis.</p>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="blue-btn title-font uppercase lightblue inline-block">Read More</a>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
       <!--    this elements repeat -->


</div>
```

Here is my SCSS code:

```
@mixin break-inside($content){
break-inside:                   $content;
-webkit-column-break-inside:    $content;
}


@mixin columns($count: 3, $gap: 10){

-webkit-column-count: $count;
-moz-column-count:    $count;
column-count:         $count;

-webkit-column-gap:   $gap;
-moz-column-gap:      $gap;
column-gap:           $gap;

}

.span-image-title {

@include columns(3,1rem);

.item { 
    @include break-inside(avoid);
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative; 
    overflow: hidden;
    width:100%; 
    margin-bottom:rem(15px); 
}

.item:hover {
    .desc-body {
        @include transition( 0.6s ease bottom , 0.3s ease background-color 0.2s );
        bottom:0;
        background-color:#f4f4f4;
    }
    .desc {
        // @include transition( 0.3s ease border-bottom 0.5s );
        // border-bottom:1px solid $text-color;
    }
    .entry-content,
    .blue-btn {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

.image {
    height:370px;
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
}

.desc {
    position: relative;
    z-index:5;
    // border-bottom:1px solid transparent;
}

.entry-content,
.blue-btn {
    @include transition( 0.5s ease opacity 0.3s , 0.3s ease transform );
    opacity: 0;
}

.desc-body {
    @include transition( 0.6s ease bottom , 0.3s ease background-color );
    margin:0 auto;
    bottom:-100%;
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.4);

}


}
```

I am using:
Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit) on Yosemite.

Comment: It works for me on Chromium 42.0.2294.0

Comment: Issue with the media query maybe? FWIW, The jsfiddle looks correct by default in both `Chrome Version 40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)` and `Firefox 35.0.1` on Linux, BUT if I drag the "Result" window bigger it breaks (center dips) on both.

Comment: I've downloaded `Chromium 42` and problem is still exists. CSS "works" but "render" fails when you scroll or hover elements. Chrome renders  without problems **just** when I remove  `transitions` or `transforms`.

Comment: Can confirm. Issue is present on Version 40.0.2214.94 m

Comment: Related problem: in Chrome, the clickable elements don't work on columns other than the first one.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The temporary solution for this was adding `transform: translateZ(0)` to my `.item` element as this enable hardware acceleration.

Comment: thank you this fixed my issue as well. Are you aware of any other solutions?

Comment: Not at the moment, sorry.

Comment: This helped me, but I'd really appreciate if you could tell how did you think of trying that?

Comment: @NikhilGirraj I've heard you can enable hardware acceleration with this CSS property, so I thought on giving a try and check if Chrome would behave different. Read more here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/increase-your-sites-performance-with-hardware-accelerated-css

Comment: `transform: translateZ(0)` fixed it for me! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not really an answer to the particular bug described here (blinking/disappearing content), but it's closely related.

I was helping a friend dealing with misaligned columns in Chrome/Safari. There were three columns and the third had phantom space above it. When we tried transform:translateZ(0) and other null transform solutions, the content **did** disappear, so that was out.

At one point he mentioned having had the idea that maybe someone had typed something into the space in the CMS, and that got me thinking about white-space, word-wrap, etc. We tried white-space:nowrap and then white-space:normal on the children, and various other related solutions, but they didn't work out.

Then he had the idea to put a negative margin on the third column div only in Chrome/Safari somehow, and that led to our discovery of this property I've never heard of before, and this wacky solution: **-webkit-margin-top-collapse:discard**.

Hope this helps some poor soul one day.

Comment: Could you explain a little more please ? On which element did you add this property ?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding `position: relative` to the transformed children elements helped a little, in addition to `transform: translateZ(0)` to parent element. Still some artefacts in transitions though... Very weird bug !

Answer (score 0):

`transform: translateZ(0);` works as Miguel Garrido suggested. However, it creates a problem of `position: absolute;` elements overlapping / underlapping (if that's a word).

Using `transform-style: preserve-3d;` eliminates this problem. 
Hope this helps someone else until the browsers fix it themselves.