# Material Design Lite Example of two column menu - not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, material-design-lite

Hey guys is there an example (with css overrides if need be) of how to have a a menu with two columns?

I am trying to do the following:

```
<span id="menu-lower-left" class="select-category"><span>Select a category</span></span>
      <ul class="category-list mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-left mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect"
          for="menu-lower-left">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Some Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Another Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Additional Action</li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item">Yet Another Action</li>
      </ul>
```

CSS looks like:
`

```
  .category-list {
    list-style-type: disc;
    columns: 2;
    -webkit-columns: 2;
    -moz-columns: 2;
    list-style-position: inside;
  }
```

`
When I try simply add 2 columns, it works but my list items disappear!

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Here is a Plunker that demonstrates the issue:

http://plnkr.co/edit/d9nNB7jg4W8nsGzdlnC4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that there is a bug in Chrome where transitions and transforms can make things disappear in multi-column layouts. Using the trick from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28618965/4912760) answer fixes it. Here is an updated Plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/st2RmkNbcJqTVaQG3Fna?p=preview
I only needed to add one thing to your CSS

```
  .mdl-menu__item {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
```